# Multiple config files with go-viper

Tags: go, viper-go

Is it possible to load/merge multiple config files with Viper? Say I have a general config file containing configuration for my program, and client specific config files with configuration for each client, where one of them would be loaded, depending on the input to the program.

Thanks.

Comment: From the docs: "Viper can search multiple paths, but currently a single Viper instance only supports a single configuration file."  https://github.com/spf13/viper#reading-config-files

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`viper` has [`ReadInConfig`](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/viper#ReadInConfig) and [`MergeInConfig`](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/viper#MergeInConfig), which can called multiple times. Here is an (untested) example:

```
viper.SetConfigName("default")
viper.AddConfigPath(path)
viper.ReadInConfig()

if context != "" {
    viper.SetConfigName(context)
    viper.AddConfigPath(path)
    viper.MergeInConfig()
}

viper.SetConfigName("config")
viper.AddConfigPath(".")
viper.MergeInConfig()
```

It reads these files in this order:

- `$path/default.[yaml|toml|json]`
- `$path/$context.[yaml|toml|json]`
- `./config.[yaml|toml|json]`

Comment: What if the configuration file name remains the same between different folders?
For example having a global config for your app in your home and then a project specific config in the cwd.
The one on your home can be called with a 'global' prefix, but keeping the same name is simpler.

Comment: @edupo Just change the `ConfigPath` in each time you load a new config file, like the example above.

Comment: `viper.AddConfigPath` adds to the global search path, it does not replace it.

Comment: sadly, enviper is [incompatible](https://github.com/iamolegga/enviper/blob/master/enviper.go#L51) with this solution

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @svenwltr won't work if you're using `viper.WatchConfig()` since it'll only watch the last config file you tell it about.

However, it'll probably work if you just create your own viper structs for each config file:

```golang
var v1, v2, v3 *viper.Viper

func init() {
    v1 = &viper.Viper{}
    v1.SetConfigName("default")
    v1.AddConfigPath(path)
    v1.ReadInConfig()
    v1.OnConfigChanged(viperConfigChanged)
    v1.WatchConfig()

    if context != "" {
        v2 = &viper.Viper{}
        v2.SetConfigName(context)
        v2.AddConfigPath(path)
        v2.MergeInConfig()
        v2.OnConfigChanged(viperConfigChanged)
        v2.WatchConfig()
    }

    v3 = &viper.Viper{}
    v3.SetConfigName("config")
    v3.AddConfigPath(".")
    v3.MergeInConfig()
    v3.OnConfigChanged(viperConfigChanged)
    v3.WatchConfig()
}

func viperConfigChanged(e fsnotify.Event) {
    fmt.Println(v1.GetString("foo"))
    if v2 != nil {
        fmt.Println(v2.GetString("bar"))
    }
    fmt.Println(v3.GetString("baz"))
}
```