# How would I Read from multiple config files and environment variables in golang viper?

Tags: go, viper-go

I'm using https://github.com/spf13/viper for configuration manager.

I've come across a use case where I've to use multiple config files `.json`, `.env` and environment variables in such a way.

- First all config from `.json` is loaded
- All non-empty variables from `.env` is loaded. Empty variables on `.env` or non-existing variables wouldn't override values from `.json`
- All non-empty variables from environment variables of platform is loaded. Empty variables on `.env` or non-existing variables wouldn't override values from `.json`

For the same purpose, I tried with following snippet but doesn't seem to work.

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
    "log"
)

type ServerConfiguration struct {
    Port int
}

type DatabaseConfiguration struct {
    ConnectionUri string
}

type Configuration struct {
    Server   ServerConfiguration
    Database DatabaseConfiguration
}

func main() {
    var configuration Configuration
    readFromConfigFile()
    readFromEnvFile()
    viper.AutomaticEnv()

    err := viper.Unmarshal(&configuration)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to decode into struct, %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("database uri is %s", configuration.Database.ConnectionUri)
    log.Printf("port for this application is %d", configuration.Server.Port)
}

func readFromConfigFile() {
    viper.SetConfigName("config")
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading config file, %s", err)
    }
}

func readFromEnvFile() {
    viper.SetConfigName(".env")
    viper.SetConfigType("env")
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")
    if err := viper.MergeInConfig(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading config file, %s", err)
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "database": {
        "connectionUri": "test uri"
    },
    "server": {
        "port": 8283
    }
}
```

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION_URI="test2 uri"
```

Expected result:

```
2023/03/15 17:07:42 database uri is test2 uri
2023/03/15 17:07:42 port for this application is 8283
```

Actual result:

```
2023/03/15 17:07:42 database uri is test uri
2023/03/15 17:07:42 port for this application is 8283
```

I tried with the suggestion mentioned here but didn't help

[Multiple config files with go-viper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47185318/multiple-config-files-with-go-viper)

Is it possible to attain as mentioned? If so, how could I achieve the functionality

Comment: You can explore for env files https://github.com/joho/godotenv

Answer (score 0):

`github.com/spf13/viper` fits your requirement perfectly.

The issue here is that the key in `.env` is incorrect. The default key delimiter is `.` (see [the source code](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/3970ad177ecc286c1e14b64c18449cb30f73d642/viper.go#L231)). So the key should be `DATABASE.CONNECTIONURI`. Here is the corrected configuration (please note that `_` in `CONNECTION_URI` should be removed too):

```
DATABASE.CONNECTIONURI="test2 uri"
```